# Using ajax with datatype json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

```
$query = "SELECT Subjects FROM instructors";
$rows = mysqli_query($con,$query);
{
    if($rows)
    {
        $count = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows))
        {
            $id = 'Name'.strval($count);
            // array_push($results,$row);
            $results[] = array($id => $row['Subjects']);
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Something wrong";
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
[{"Name0":"lore"},{"Name1":"ipsum"}]
```

Now in JS, I would like to get these names.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: "get_subs.php",
 dataType :"JSON",
 success : function(data)
 {
    alert(data);
 }
    })
});
```

But this only prints

```
0 => [object Object]
```

I also tried

```
alert(data.Name0);
```

But that also alerts the same thing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use something like `console.log( JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) );` for readable output

Comment: alert() is not a debugging tool, so your problem is trying to debug code with something that is meant for simple messages for the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is an array, so you need to access it by index:

```
alert(data[0].Name0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.stringify and see what it outputs. It's normal that when you alert something like an object or an array it outputs that.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```